# Have Bone/Pose position layers moved?

Tags: armature, layers

[![layers not shown][1]][1]

Image 2 is of Blender 4.0 version which doesn't show skeleton, instead it shows something pose and also it doesn't show 32 layers as that of image 1.

How can I fix it? I am stuck without this fixing this issue and can't move further.

Comment: Layers are now bone collections if I recall correctly

Answer (score 3):

This is the new collection system for organizing bones.

[image]